# Unlimited posts in custom layout PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I am working on a Wordpress website with the posts showing in two columns running with a PHP code. The problem I am facing is that the posts showing on the website are limited to 10. Does anyone know where in the code I can make a change to show unlimited posts? Or do I need a whole new PHP code for this?

Would like to hear from you!

This is the code I am using

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
if($i == 0) {echo '<div class="ng-row">';}?>

<div class="half">

<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>


<?php the_content(); ?>


</div>


<?php $i++; if($i == 2) {$i = 0;echo '</div>';}?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<?php if($i > 0) {echo '</div>';}?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I've tried to change the numbers but it didn't work out well..

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: I have changed the question, not really sure what you ment with what I have to change.. But it's now asked in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

For an unlimited return set the `posts_per_page` to -1

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts',  'set_posts_per_page'  );
function set_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    // This will set the query to return all results
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );

    return $query;
}
```

Although be aware that this can be very bad for performance depending on the amount of posts. It should really only be done if you have a limited result set and know what that is.